# SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character error in AJAX call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I'm an engineering intern at a software company, and my current project is to create an HTML page that uses AJAX and PHP to get data from a database. I've never posted on this site before, I've always looked for similar posts and used the info I find. I've been looking for a solution to my problem for the last 2 hours or so. My AJAX call returns the error: "SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data."

I've tried lots of things, namely:

1. Adding dataType: 'json' to the options in $.ajax.
2. Adding header("Content-type: application/json"); to the PHP code.
3. Using console.log($.parseJSON(data)) in the success function.
4. Reformatting my code in PHP to include quotes or not include them in the array

It seems like the problem is in the formatting of the data my page receives from my PHP script, which is as follows:

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
$testarray = array("Name" => 'America', "Code" => '12345');
echo json_encode($testarray);
```

In my jquery segment, I want to retrieve JSON data from my PHP script (which will eventually use a MySQL DB) and add the data as elements in my list box, CountriesList. My AJAX call is as follows:

```
$.ajax({
     cache: false,
     url: 'results.php',
     method: 'POST',
     dataType: 'json',
     data: "",
     success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR){
           //I get an error with the following line
           var jsonData = JSON.parse(data);
           $(jsonData).each(function (i, element)
           {
                 var htmlSelect = document.getElementById("CountriesList");
                 var opt = document.createElement("option");
                 opt.text = element.Name;
                 opt.value = element.Code;
                 htmlSelect.options.add(opt);
            });
            },
            error: function(jsXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
            {
                        alert('Error: ' + errorThrown)
            }
             });
```

It's possible that there are other errors in this code since I haven't been able to debug past this formatting issue. When I open the PHP script by itself, I get this as a response: {"Name":"America","Code":"12345"}. Which, as far as I'm aware, is correctly formatted JSON.

I'm at a loss. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: is the response not already json I don't think you need to parse it. Try console.log(JSON.stringify(data)); and if that out puts a JSON string you have already got JSON

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ill put this as an answer.

As I said in my comment the data variable is already a JSON object. So you should be able to access each element like so:

```
for(var i in data){
    if(data.hasOwnProperty(i){
        $('#CountriesList').append($("<option></option>").attr("value",data[i].Value).text(data[i].Name));
    }
}
```

Your test array is just an associative array whereas the javascript is expecting an array of associative arrays. Try

```
$testarray = array();
$testarray[] = array('Name'=>'America', 'Value'=>'12345');
$testarray[] = array('Name'=>'Europe', 'Value'=>'54321');
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I tried putting that in, and my new success function just contains your code.

But it still gives me the exact same error.

Comment: I tried commenting out the dataType: 'json', and it didn't give me the syntax error, but now your code returns "undefined".

Comment: @ChristieFrieg that could be because your test array is really an associative array, try changing the php to $testarray = array(array("Name" => 'America', "Code" => '12345')); And add datatype json back in.

Comment: I had it pop up an alert with the data, and when I commented out the dataType, it returned this: "<html>

<body>

    {"Name":"America","Code":"12345"}</body>

</html>
" Which is not JSON, even though I used json_encode in my php. I'm just continuing to get more and more confused.

Comment: OKAY I figured out the problem. I had used a PHP file my partner in the project sent me, which was originally sending data to a different page. She put <html><body> at the top and bottom, and the php was in a php tag. So it was returning the contents of the PHP file, which of course, was not in JSON format. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

The variable data is in JSON format, jQuery does it for you if you add dataType: json or the php header.

So you have to change:

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse(data);
By:
var jsonData = data;
```

Comment: I tried that option, but then I couldn't access it in my loop. My current loop allows me to access each element using element.<fieldname>, and when I just set the variable to the data with no parsing, nothing happened when I assigned a variable to that element.Name or element.Code. Is there a better way to access each key/value pair in my loop?

Answer (score -1):

If you need POST, this should work (you don't need to parse an array encoded by PHP in json):

```
$.post('results.php', // url
        {argOne: "test", argTwo: "test"}, // post data
        function(jsonResponse) { // callback

            $(jsonResponse).each(function (i, element) {
                // do your things
            });
         },'json');
```

If you can use GET method:

```
$.getJSON("results.php", function(jsonResponse) { 

    $(jsonResponse).each(function (i, element) {
        // do your things
    });                           
});
```